# Azure Mobile App query - bad request

Tags: azure

I have modified the sample ToDoItem app to connect my app an Azure Mobile App service.  I recreated most steps slowly to get the hang of it and it mostly works.

I'm stumped on one query with a Where clause.  I have other queries with where clauses but for some reason this one doesn't work.  I've checked whether the types match up from the underlying database table to the back end classes, to the front end classes and I can't find anything obvious.  My front end classes don't have JSON property types on them - not sure whether that is required as the rest of the stuff is working without them.

Here is the where clause that's returning a 'Bad Request'

```
string _test = txtEmail.Text;
    var _userlist = await userTable
                      .Where(User => User.eMail == _test)
                      .ToCollectionAsync();
```

Here is my front end class;

```
public class User
   {
      private IMobileServiceTable<User> userTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<User>();
      private ApplicationDataContainer localSettings;

      //
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string UserID { get; set; }
      public string UserName { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public bool DefaultUser { get; set; }
      public string eMail { get; set; }
      public bool LocationPermission { get; set; }
      public bool CloudPermission { get; set; }

      public User()
      {
         Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();
         UserID = _id.ToString();
      }//constructor
```

And my table schema;

```
[Id]                 NVARCHAR (128)     DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [UserID]             NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [UserName]           NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [FirstName]          NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [LastName]           NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [DefaultUser]        BIT                NOT NULL,
    [eMail]              NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [LocationPermission] BIT                NOT NULL,
    [CloudPermission]    BIT                NOT NULL,
    [Version]            ROWVERSION         NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt]          DATETIMEOFFSET (7) DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt]          DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [Deleted]            BIT                NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

Hopefully someone can help point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: I've actually tried the where clause on other columns. eg. FirstName - and it works fine!  Can get all the other columns to work just not eMail.

Comment: I've found out more.  I turned on logs on my Azure service and here is the actual error.  Somewhere it is trying to look for 'EMail', with a capital E.  Not sure why the backend code is doing that.  It looks right.  Buffer="{"message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'EMail' on type 'MyVinylServiceService.DataObjects.User'."}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Think I solved this, but not sure really why.  The eMail attribute was the only one with a lower case start.  I changed it to EMail and all worked fine.  Not sure why - something in Entity Framework maybe.